# Manipulating DOM elements in AngularJS partial views using jQuery

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I've got a fairly basic AngularJS app that has a couple of partial views - a search form and a results table. I'm now trying to add a jQuery UI slider to part of my results view, but I've realised that the jQuery code will only affect elements in my main index.html, and not the partial views. How can I target elements inside a partial view with jQuery?

Comment: I've heard about AngularJS development that you should try to avoid falling back to jQuery and use AngularJS for everything. It might be hard in the beginning but once you got the angular 'feeling' you won't need any jquery anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but there's no way (as far as I'm aware) to create a slider in Angular, so I'll need to use jQuery

Comment: This isn't an answer to your direct question, but a solution might be to reference the values of the slider with a variable in the parent controller, then the elements in the child templates can reference the variable within their scope.  Just a thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't used jQuery UI for everything else, there seems to be a slider code on plunker: http://plnkr.co/gqLh8PreNMBcAeXeRZF7

I got there from https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui/issues/252